# Scrapy xpath selector doesnt select all the HTML tags

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape all the product names on https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=ps3&cat_id=0 using the Scrapy python library.

This is my parse function

```html
    def parseWalmart(self,response):

        print("INSIDE PARSE WALMART")

        for product in response.xpath('//div[@id="searchProductResult"]/div[@class="search-result-listview-items"]//div[starts-with(@data-tl-id,"ProductTileListView-")]'):

            print(product)
            product_name = product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"search-result-product-title listview")]//a//span//text()').extract()
            product_page = product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"search-result-product-title listview")]//a/@href').extract()

            product_name=" ".join(product_name)
            print(product_name)
            print("-------------------------------------")
```

and this is my scrapy request

```
    yield scrapy.Request(url=i, callback=self.parseWalmart, headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
```

However, I am only able to scrape 4 products, when there are actually a dozen of them. I dont understand why. These are the 4 products that I scraped

```html
<Selector xpath='//div[@id="searchProductResult"]/div[@class="search-result-listview-items"]//div[starts-with(@data-tl-id,"ProductTileListView-")]' data='<div data-tl-id="ProductTileListView-0">'>
ABLEGRID Wireless Bluetooth Game Controller for Sony  PS3  Black
-------------------------------------
<Selector xpath='//div[@id="searchProductResult"]/div[@class="search-result-listview-items"]//div[starts-with(@data-tl-id,"ProductTileListView-")]' data='<div data-tl-id="ProductTileListView-1">'>
Arsenal Gaming  PS3  Wired Controller, Black
-------------------------------------
<Selector xpath='//div[@id="searchProductResult"]/div[@class="search-result-listview-items"]//div[starts-with(@data-tl-id,"ProductTileListView-")]' data='<div data-tl-id="ProductTileListView-2">'>
Refurbished Sony PlayStation 3 Slim 320 GB Charcoal Black Console
-------------------------------------
<Selector xpath='//div[@id="searchProductResult"]/div[@class="search-result-listview-items"]//div[starts-with(@data-tl-id,"ProductTileListView-")]' data='<div data-tl-id="ProductTileListView-3">'>
Sonic's Ultimate Genesis Collection ( PS3 )
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Because there are only 4 divs starting with 'ProductTileListView-' in the DOM originally. However, you can find all products information in the script of the page.

Here is how I get all information of product

`import re
import json
data = re.findall("\"items\":(.+?),\"secondaryItems\"", response.body.decode("utf-8"), re.S)
products_json = json.loads(data[0])
len(ls) # return 20`

Notice that the products array starts with "items": and ends with ,"secondaryItems".

structure of one product

`{
  "productId": "2H53I08Z1K78",
  "usItemId": "23422902",
  "productType": "REGULAR",
  "title": "Watch Dogs (<mark>PS3</mark>)",
  ....
  "imageUrl": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/70aecbb1-5dbf-4a64-a86d-134a8fc7edee_2.59805d79db07665c20cc4e4fadc35743.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff",
  "productPageUrl": "/ip/Watch-Dogs-PS3/23422902",
  "upc": "0000888834804",
}`

Comment: I dont see the json "items" in the GET request to https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=ps3&cat_id=0

Comment: @darbulix I believe the screenshot says everything you need.

Comment: I am saying that I dont get what you get on your dev tools

Comment: I know how to use the inspector, but when I go under Network, I dont get exactly what you get for under Response. Could you maybe walk through the steps you took to get to that point?

Comment: Find the correct doc which is what exactly server returns. If the doc is empty, force to browser to reload all resources in the page. You may want to pretty print it.